# Seamlessly support serialization to json and csv from NestJS controllers

Tags: nestjs

In spring, you could activate support for returning json or csv by attaching .json or .csv to the rest request, and the data would be returned in the requested format. I've looked over the NestJS docs, and short of handling the raw response manually and doing my own json to csv conversion, there doesn't seem to be a way to do this.

I have a project with dozens of rest routes, I'm ideally searching for a solution that at worst, would involve a custom controller decorator that would introspect requests, and serialize to csv if the .csv extension was added to the rest request. I would be ok with writing the decorator, but I'm not sure where to start, or if this is possible?

Comment: This should be pretty straightforward to accomplish using interceptors. They can conditionally manipulate the output data before it is sent back

Comment: I think [this example](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nest-content-negotiation) would be a good start point to what Jesse mentioned. This is specifically for the `Content-Type header, but you can make it work with the url instead.

Comment: @JayMcDoniel That is wonderful, if you post that example link as an answer I will accept-